# How to delete a folder containing trailing spaces

Tags: windows-xp

I have a bunch of folders on my hardrive that have trailing spaces in them (I have no idea how they got there). I need to rename and/or delete them, but Windows won't allow me to do this. Is there a way around this problem?

I've tried to delete it via the commandline, but that did not work.

I'm running Windows XP, and it's an [NTFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) drive.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First try some quoting:

```
rd "my folder   "
```

Then UNC paths:

```
rd "\\.\C:\temp\my folder   "
```

Then try adding a trailing [back]slash:

```
rd "my folder   \"
rd "\\.\C:\temp\my folder   \"
```

Then 8.3 names (if they are enabled on your system):

```
rd myfold~1
```

Then [a Linux LiveCD](http://www.ubuntu.com/):

```
rmdir "/media/blahblah/temp/my folder   "
```

Comment: Deleting using the 8.3 names worked. Thanks

Comment: "mydomain.com " as a folder. DOS thought the 8.3 filename was "mydoma~1.com". But it worked. Super thanks!

Comment: Backslash method worked for me on Windows 10

Comment: For those who look for a more user-friendly solution, I uploaded a registry file on GitHub which you can import on your computer. This will add two new context menu options to your right-click, one to delete files with trailing spaces and one for folders. See https://github.com/thomaspdt/delete-file-with-space

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem, in Windows 7 x64, and none of the command-line solutions worked here.

What fixed it for me:

- Rename the folder using [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)
- Delete, either using 7-Zip or Explorer (both work)

Note that deleting the folder in 7-Zip *before* renaming it was impossible.

Comment: 7-Zip worked for be on a 2008R2 trailing folder that I could not delete.

Comment: Thanks this was the only method that worked for me on a folder mounted from a remote file server

Comment: This workaround worked on windows server 2019

Answer (score 7):

windows 7

I was having issues getting rid of a folder. 
**`"C:\Users\Rob\Desktop\Music\ A k o n "`**

This is what finally worked for me: 
I opened up the cmd prompt in the Music folder 
(**shift right click**, ***open command window here***)

then typed in the following command

**`rd " A k o n \"`**

**notice the back slash.**

beginning spaces and trailing spaces really mess crap up.
I spent at least 2 hours searching for a solution.

Thank you **grawity** for posting the solution.

Answer (score 4):

There is still not the best support for trailing spaces in folder names on Windows. Most commands will work, when using [UNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Universal_Naming_Convention) paths.

**Windows command prompt**

Creating a folder with a trailing space in its name:

```
md "\\?\C:\FolderWithTrailingSpace "
```

Renaming a folder with a trailing space in its name seems to require a workaround. Create a folder with the new name, move the content to it, delete the old folder:

```
md "C:\FolderWithoutTrailingSpace"
move "\\?\C:\FolderWithTrailingSpace \*" "C:\FolderWithoutTrailingSpace"
rd "\\?\C:\FolderWithTrailingSpace "
```

Deleting a folder with a trailing space in its name:

```
rd "\\?\C:\FolderWithTrailingSpace "
```

**Windows PowerShell**

Creating a folder with a trailing space in its name:

```
New-Item -Path "\\?\C:\FolderWithTrailingSpace " -Type Directory
```

Renaming a folder with a trailing space in its name:

```
Rename-Item -LiteralPath "\\?\C:\FolderWithTrailingSpace " -NewName "\\?\C:\RenamedFolderWithTrailingSpace "
```

Deleting a folder with a trailing space in its name:

```
Remove-Item -LiteralPath "\\?\C:\FolderWithTrailingSpace "
```

**Workaround for `cd`/`Set-Location`**

In order to change your directory to a folder that contains a trailing space in its name, you can use a workaround with symbolic links. Create a symbolic link to the folder with a trailing space in its name using the `mklink` command of an elevated Windows command prompt (not available in PS):

```
mklink /D "C:\FolderWithoutTrailingSpace" "\\?\C:\FolderWithTrailingSpace "
```

After that, you can use `cd` in the command prompt or in PowerShell to switch to that directory:

```
cd C:\FolderWithoutTrailingSpace
```

Or use `Set-Location` in PowerShell:

```
Set-Location -LiteralPath "C:\FolderWithoutTrailingSpace"
```

Answer (score 1):

Then the DOS name:

```
dir /x
rd FOLDER~1
```

Then the (UNC?) name which I'm not sure how to find or what exactly it looks like:

```
rd \Device\HarddiskVolume1\temp\folder
rd \\?\Device\HarddiskVolume1\temp\folder
```

Comment: System-local UNC paths start with `\\.\` for devices and `\\?\` for files ([official doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx)); using `\\?\C:\` is often enough.

Answer (score 1):

RoboCopy seems particularly good at addressing folders/paths verbatim, so you could make an empty folder alongside the parent of the folder that has your erroneously named folder and then copy the empty folder to be the parent folder path and specify the PURGE option, which will purge the other entries in the destination folder. Hopefully you will also ensure that only bad folders are there

In summary, you want to copy 0 files into the folder that houses your bad folder, and specify /purge so that the operation clears out anything else in the folder (including your bad folder)

Confused? Then an example will surely help. Suppose you have:

```
C:\path\leading-to-a\folder-with-space \
```

Run these commands:

```
cd c:\path\
mkdir empty
robocopy empty leading-to-a /purge
```

robocopy will copy the *empty* folder to the *leading-to-a* folder, and purge the other entries in the leading-to-a folder, one of which is your folder with a trailing space:

> ---
>
> ```
>   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
>  Started : Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970
>
>   Source : C:\path\empty\
>     Dest : C:\path\leading-to-a\
>
>    Files : *.*
>
>  Options : *.* /COPY:DAT /PURGE /R:1000000 /W:30
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
>                           0    C:\path\empty\
>        *EXTRA Dir        -1    C:\path\leading-to-a\folder-with-spaces \
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
>               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
>    Dirs :         1         0         1         0         0         1
>   Files :         0         0         0         0         0         0
>   Bytes :         0         0         0         0         0         0
>   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00
>
>   Ended : Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970
> ```

**Warning:**

Make sure that anything you want to keep is moved out of the *leading-to-a* folder first!

Answer (score 0):

Boot with a [live CD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD) of Ubuntu, and you will be able to delete anything you want.

To boot with the CD you should change the boot order in your [BIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS) settings.

Answer (score 0):

Use WinRAR to find that file and rename it without the space at the end. You should be able to delete it!