# Rename/delete Windows (x64) folder with leading and trailing space

Tags: windows-7

I have created a folder via [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), but I made a mistake since I forgot to clear spaces. Now I cannot delete this folder.

I have found a similar issue here - [look at the second answer](https://superuser.com/questions/198256/how-to-delete-a-folder-containing-trailing-spaces/366583#366583) (Quoted below), but I don't know how to rename a folder with [7-Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip).

> I had the same problem, in Windows 7 x64, and none of the command-line solutions worked here.
>
> What fixed it for me:
>
> - Rename the folder using 7-Zip
> - Delete, either using 7-Zip or [Windows Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Explorer) (both work).
>
> Note that deleting the folder in 7-Zip before renaming it was impossible.

I also tried the command line, but it does not work. My folder is named `" 1 "`.

I downloaded 7-Zip, and Google does not provide the help I need.

Comment: Folder names that start and end with spaces shouldn't be a problem on Win7.  I was able to create a folder named " 1 " and then delete without problem using just the `mkdir` and `rmdir` commands built into `cmd.exe`.  Is it possible the name contains other characters?  E.g., are those double quotes part of the name or is it possible those spaces aren't spaces and displaying as spaces?

Comment: I have to agree with Nicole, here must be something else you guys are missing. Leading or trailing spaces are no problem for Windows 7 using mkdir to create a folder called "  test  " and normal deletion via Explorer afterwards

Comment: Great solutiion i had a file named "Invisble, Inc." which was created by Steam and belonged to the game Invisible Inc. Using 7 zip i was able to rename it and after that deleting it.

Comment: I had this issue as well on Win7x32. After creating a folder without the space, I was able to rename the old one (ie: new folder "1" and then delete "1 ")

Comment: You could use `mv.exe` from GnuWin32 or Cygwin. On Windows 10, use `wsl mv` from Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Find the item you want renamed in the main window. Then right click the file/folder in the list and click "rename".

You could also select it by clicking it once and press <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Edit:

Try this from the commandline:

```
rename "\\?\c:\<PATH HERE>\[ ]1[ ]" "<NEW FILE NAME>"
```

or

```
rename "\\?\c:\<PATH HERE>\ 1 " "<NEW FILE NAME>"
```

Mind you, the NEW FILE NAME doesn't take the full path, so just use the file's name. PATH HERE is just the path without the file.

Comment: With the first example : not found -

With the second : incorrect syntax -

Should I do it from the root ?

Comment: I used `cd` to go to images, and from there :
`\\?\C:\Websites\education-fonctionnelle\images\[ ]1[ ]" "2"` => not found.

`\\?\C:\Websites\education-fonctionnelle\images\ 1 " "2"` => incorrect syntax

Comment: @Ocelote, after the NEW FILE NAME, you should end with a `"`. I don't see this in your comment, did you use this? so: `\\?\C:\Websites\education-fonctionnelle\images\[ ]1[ ]" "2"`

Comment: @Ocelote, would it be okay to transfer the files to a new folder and delete the old, defective one? If so, empty the folder and try `rd "\\?\C:\Websites\education-fonctionnelle\images\[ ]1[ ]"` This will **remove** the directory.

Comment: Yes it is possible, I have a clean copy zipped with 7z from where it is possible to remove/rename. With your command (also tested with spaces) I get `File not found`

Comment: @Ocelote then the last thing I can think of is 1) Using a Linux LiveCD or 2) Deleting the parent folder.

Comment: After rebooting my computer, it has disapeared, I will try with the second folder.

Comment: I managed to do it again. For whoever passes by here try the command lines above. I also tried `rd "\\?\C:\Websites\education-fonctionnelle\images\[ ]1[ ]" "2"` (which is not correct but still, it is part of what I did)

THANK YOU !!!!!!!

Comment: I have a folder with a blank space at the end. Nothing from this answer or the comments have worked. Possibly not possible in Server 2012.

Comment: Does not work for all strange characters. 7zip did.

Answer (score 34):

The answer from @Ocelot did not work on Windows Server 2008 R2. What did work was:

Open a command, change to the directory and do a "dir /x". You will see the long and the short name of the directory. You can always rename the short version as it does not contain spaces most of the time. So a `ren 3839F~1.4_T whatever` should be possible.

Comment: This is the correct answer with the current versions of the operating system. Smart, using the 8.3 file name support. I wonder why the "\\?\" hardware path was is longer supported, that is also required to support paths with a total length of more than 250-odd characters.

Comment: this works for folders with a shortname...if you find yourself in the unfortunate position with no shortname you'll have to use a third-party tool (mingw64 which comes with git worked for me), this also wroked for me `https://stackoverflow.com/a/21074385/167304`

Comment: Worked on Windows 10, but not Windows 2012R2 for me: Some NTFS versions no longer generate 8.3 filenames. the 7Zip method below worked on everything.

Comment: wow nice trick, worked

Answer (score 30):

I just had a similar problem with folder "Monuments - Discography " created in linux. Windows Vista and Windows 7 couldn't recognize this folder as a valid data and when I tried to rename or remove it I got Info message saying that folder does not exist etc. The solution was to **explore a dir with 7zip file manager and rename the folder by removing a white space from the end.**  Simple. Now I can enjoy the music once again :D

Comment: The OP said in their question that they do not know how to rename a folder using 7-zip. Can you please explain how to do that? Thanks.

Comment: press f2 like in windows explorer. Note you need the GUI filemanager of 7z, "7zFM.exe"

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 10 when all the rest failed

Comment: I searched for several days. DotNet solution in C# failed, with administrator priviliges failed, just using [7Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html) worked. Windows 10, directory created by NextCloud with space at the end.

Answer (score 9):

As I was not able to reproduce the solution of the [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/565335/1077440), and other answers did not help either (except the 8.3 naming workaround), I want to share some methods that I already included in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1550630/1077440):

**Windows command prompt**

Creating a folder with a trailing space in its name:

```
md "\\?\C:\FolderWithTrailingSpace "
```

Renaming a folder with a trailing space in its name seems to require a workaround. Create a folder with the new name, move the content to it, delete the old folder:

```
md "C:\FolderWithoutTrailingSpace"
move "\\?\C:\FolderWithTrailingSpace \*" "C:\FolderWithoutTrailingSpace"
rd "\\?\C:\FolderWithTrailingSpace "
```

Deleting a folder with a trailing space in its name:

```
rd "\\?\C:\FolderWithTrailingSpace "
```

**Windows PowerShell**

Creating a folder with a trailing space in its name:

```
New-Item -Path "\\?\C:\FolderWithTrailingSpace " -Type Directory
```

Renaming a folder with a trailing space in its name:

```
Rename-Item -LiteralPath "\\?\C:\FolderWithTrailingSpace " -NewName "\\?\C:\RenamedFolderWithTrailingSpace "
```

Deleting a folder with a trailing space in its name:

```
Remove-Item -LiteralPath "\\?\C:\FolderWithTrailingSpace "
```

**Workaround for `cd`/`Set-Location`**

In order to change your directory to a folder that contains a trailing space in its name, you can use a workaround with symbolic links. Create a symbolic link to the folder with a trailing space in its name using the `mklink` command of an elevated Windows command prompt (not available in PS):

```
mklink /D "C:\FolderWithoutTrailingSpace" "\\?\C:\FolderWithTrailingSpace "
```

After that, you can use `cd` in the command prompt or in PowerShell to switch to that directory:

```
cd C:\FolderWithoutTrailingSpace
```

Or use `Set-Location` in PowerShell:

```
Set-Location -LiteralPath "C:\FolderWithoutTrailingSpace"
```

Comment: Remove-Item -LiteralPath "\\?\drive:\FolderWithTrailingPeriod." -Force -Recurse was the only solution that worked for me, I had a non-empty directory and the directory ended with a "."

Answer (score 4):

Use the old DOS 8.3 naming method:

If the directory was called "Blah " then you could cd Blah~1 for example. Delete the contents of the folder, then at the root you could rmdir Blah~1

Comment: I had a folder called `test` and another called `test <space>`.  `rmdir TEST~1` removed the one with a space.  This is a nice trick for those that do not have 7zip around.

Answer (score 4):

Install winrar.  Open it up, navigate to the file location, and you should be able to rename it.  (I was having the same problem and this worked for me).

Comment: Winrar works but you need to run it as an "Administrator".

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem. After using a renaming utility, I discovered that I had four files that had a leading space. I tried renaming it, but Windows coughed and said that the names couldn't be changed.

I decided to add a character (in my case, I just typed "1") in front of the leading space and I could save it (renamed). I then could rename the file by removing the character (again, in my case I just added a "1") and the aforementioned leading space without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Windows 7? Try to do a `chkdsk /f` on the affected drive. It should correct illegal filenames (beware: it will move the files to a `FOUND.000` folder on the root)

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers, oddly, no longer work with Win10/Server 201X.

I found the only thing that did work was using the short name.

Situation: QT allowed me to create a directory with a trailing space. I found that:
rmdir * didn't work (I had 3 such directories)

rmdir "director with space " didn't remove it with CMD.

rmdir * /s (TCC from JPSoft) didn't do it.

The Explorer wouldn't remove it; I kept getting an error that the directory no longer existed. I also have Win10 in developer mode.

Powershell wouldn't do it.

The \?\ syntax wouldn't do it.

However, dir /x and then using the shortname to remove the directory worked fine.

I would have made a comment to @rantygrant but my SO rep doesn't follow me here, so I made an answer to explicitly mention most of the other answers are now broken in Win10. Here's hoping you still have compatibility with 8.3 turned on. I did not try the 7-zip solution.

Comment: Tried all these in Win10, nothing worked. dir /x showed no 8.3 filenames at all. Finally, rename from inside WinRAR worked.

Comment: Hey, it's great that worked! I didn't need to try it, and once they were gone, I didn't have a chance to check WinRAR. Glad it worked for you! Thanks for commenting so others have two potential ways to do it.

Answer (score -3):

I had two files, one with a space at the end, and the other with a period at the end. Windows refused to allow me to rename or delete either. I tried doing it through Python's os module, as well, to no avail. The solution that finally worked for me was to open a command prompt (cmd.exe), cd to the folder, and then run the command:

```
del *.*
```

Of course, this means moving everything you want to keep out of the folder first.

EDIT: Sorry, reread the question and realized you are talking about a folder, not a file, so my answer really doesn't help you, but I'm going to leave it here for anyone else who has similar issues.

Comment: It's pretty dangerous to suggest things like this.  People who don't know what they're doing will delete everything by accident.