# Directory can only be accessed with explorer

Tags: windows, filesystem-corruption

This is a strange situation that I don't really know why it's happening.

Let's say I have these directories (names are fake but the structure is real):

```
a
+- b
|  + file1
|  + file2
|
+- c
   + file3
   + file4
```

I can navigate to all three directories without problems in the explorer. However when I try to `cd` into `b` and `c`, I got this

```
C:\PathToUser\a> cd "b"
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

This is strange because they are clearly there:

```
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is SOME-NUMS

 Directory of C:\PathToUser\a

12/12/2017  11:56 PM    <DIR>          .
12/12/2017  11:56 PM    <DIR>          ..
01/29/2012  10:54 PM    <DIR>          b
01/29/2012  10:32 PM    <DIR>          c
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  SOME bytes free
```

What I wanted to do is to remove those two directories, but I couldn't remove them with both `cmd` and explorer. Are the directories corrupted? Any suggestion is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Real rather than hypothetical names would help: spaces need quotes around path name, and other characters can be problematic.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik The directory names do include spaces (`0x20`) but that's about it. The `"b"` in `cd "b"` is autocompleted by pressing tab so the name should be accurate.

Comment: Does it include spaces _at the end_?

Comment: @grawity For some reason they do! (In fact it has two spaces) I have no idea why there are spaces at the end. The directories were probably generated at some point.

Comment: Never mind, [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/866217/146186) solved my problem.