# windows 10 remove folder: paths does not exists but

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I'm facing the following problem:

[image]

that is `Get-ChildItem` shows the directory but `Remove-Item` says that it does not exist !!

I yet try chkdsk, file explorer, trying to rename it,... but I just can't remove that directory

please help.

---

```
Gci . -dir|%{Remove-Item -LiteralPath "$($_.FullName)"}
```

gives:

```
Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'D:\data\inpibug\ustocks ' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:14
+ Gci . -dir|%{Remove-Item -LiteralPath "$($_.FullName)"}
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\data\inpibug\ustocks :String) [Remove-Item], ItemNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text but the text itself. The error msg shows a trailing space or other char in the quoted folder name. Try `Gci . -dir|%{Remove-Item -LiteralPath "$($_.FullName)"}`

Comment: yes there is a trailing space

Comment: Could you please try the solutions in this question: https://superuser.com/questions/565334/rename-delete-windows-x64-folder-with-leading-and-trailing-space?

Comment: @AulisRonkainen wow, nice ! It did it!